# CSS :not for a specific td with :before selector in responsive table

Tags: html, css

I made a responsive css table and if I click on a `<tr>` I get an output in a hidden row. Of course when I resize the window to a phone display size the `:before` selector will display a content for that row which I don't want to happen. Let me show you the code.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.record td').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent('.record').next('.companion').toggle();
    var msgid = $(this).parent('.record').attr("id");
    var dataString13 = 'msgid=' + msgid;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "view_msg.php",
      data: dataString13,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        if (data == 0) {
          alert('Not Sent!');
        } else {
          //$('a#'+msgid).html(data);
          //$('.viewmessage'+msgid).hide();
          //$('a#'+msgid).html('<img src="img/loader.gif" class="loading" />'); 
          $('#corpmesaj').html('<img src="img/loader.gif" class="loading" />'); 
          $('#corpmesaj').html(data); 
          $('.o'+msgid).html(data);
          // $(this).parent('.record').next('.companion').html(data);
          //$(this).parent('.record').addClass('recorded');
          //$(this).parent('.record').removeClass('record');
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
/* 
Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
*/
table { 
    width: 100%; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
    background: #eee; 
}
th { 
    background: #333; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
td, th { 
    padding: 6px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    text-align: left; 
}
/* 
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
    }
    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }
    tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
    td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
    }

    td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    /* Label the data */
    td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Subject"; }
    td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Date"; }
    td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Actions"; }
}
```

```html
<table class="rules">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="record">

        <td class="overflow">
           <div class="toggle enabled"></div>  John Doe
        </td>
        <td class="overflow" title="Sunshine Northwind Systems, Incorporate (Really Long Company Name): Note the elipsis">
          Sunshine Westwind Systems, Incorporate
        </td>
        <td class="date">
          2013/12/13
        </td>
        <td class="last">
          <a href="#"><img class="filter" src="a.jpg" width="26" /></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="companion">
        <td class="output" colspan="4">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum pharetra nunc sit amet arcu dignissim, vestibulum pharetra turpis bibendum. Donec nisi felis, elementum ut lectus vitae, sagittis condimentum sem. Praesent at sapien turpis. Maecenas feugiat feugiat est, vel hendrerit elit congue vitae. Fusce quis velit sed urna ultricies molestie quis non neque. Vestibulum ultrices quam et enim fringilla tempus. Cras ornare magna eu pellentesque elementum. Duis vel magna eget lacus imperdiet consequat. Mauris cursus porttitor vulputate. Ut egestas diam vitae massa tincidunt, et tempus dui laoreet. Praesent consequat turpis ac ante pretium, id auctor ante aliquet.
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4"></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

As you can see the `<td class="output">` will be filled with my output from javascript and with "Name" word from css selector and this is not what I intend to do.

EDIT: I uploaded an image to show you the problem: [image: CSS Responsive Table]

Comment: and what do you want exactly?

Comment: When i connect to that page from a mobile device to have these selectors working td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Subject"; }
    td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Date"; }
    td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Actions"; } excepting the  <tr class="companion">.

Comment: There's way too much code in this question. My guess is that you could convey your challenge with a three-row table and a bit of CSS. The jQuery doesn't even seem relevant.

Comment: Why have you placed the `:before` content first place in CSS for mobile layout if you do not want it? Can you be more accurate?

Comment: I want it but not for that row with "companion" class. That's a hidden row wich is shown when i click on the row with  "record"  class. That's why i don't need the CSS layout for all rows. I can't figure out how to use :before in the same time with :not(.companion).

Comment: Wouldn't `td.companion::before { content: none }` after other `::before` selectors be enough to turn off pseudo-element generation for that `td`?

Answer (score 0):

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a
>   simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an
>   argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its
>   argument.
>
> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector,
>   attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

As you can see from the above statements, :not() takes in only a simple selector as argument and pseudo-elements do not fall under the simple selector category. Hence, no, you cannot achieve what you are trying in the way you are trying.

One way to achieve what you're trying to do is override the property, for example setting it to `font-size:0px;` when you don't want to display it.

Or removing the property using jquery `$('selector').removeClass('classToRemove');`
Where, in this case, you had to put the desired only mobile or only pc stylings on that class to remove (or add) when needed.

Another way could be using scss (SASS).

Hope it helps!